# Dynamic form validation in angular 6 with condition and vice versa

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on angular 6 with dynamic form validation. I have three form fields `gender` which is initially with required validation; `ageFrom` and `ageTo` which are to be validated dynamically. If `ageFrom`value is first entered then the validation for `ageTo` is to be made required where as when `ageTo` value is first entered then the validation for `ageFrom` is to be made required.
My code is as below:

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
          ageTo: [''],
          ageFrom: [''],
          gender: new FormControl('', Validators.required),

      });

      const ageFrom = <FormControl>this.formGroup.get('ageFrom');
      const ageTo = <FormControl>this.formGroup.get('ageTo');

      this.subscription = ageFrom.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
          if (value) {
              ageTo.setValidators([Validators.required,]);
          } else {
              ageTo.setValidators([Validators.nullValidator,]);
          }
          this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
      });

      this.subscription = ageTo.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
          if (value) {
              ageFrom.setValidators([Validators.required,]);
          } else {
              ageFrom.setValidators([Validators.nullValidator,]);
          }
          this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
      });
```

After this code as it goes on infinite loops. It gives
`ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`
How can I solve that conditional and vice versa dynamic form validation.

Comment: The infinite loop is expected. Change the updateValueAndValidity to trigger only on the control you are changing instead of on the entire group..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set emitEvent false to updateValueandValidity method.

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
        const ageFrom = <FormControl>this.formGroup.get("ageFrom");
        const ageTo = <FormControl>this.formGroup.get("ageTo");

        ageFrom.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
          console.log(value, "ageFrom");
          if (value) {
            ageTo.setValidators(Validators.required);
          } else {
            ageTo.setValidators(Validators.nullValidator);
          }
          ageTo.updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false });
        });

        ageTo.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
          console.log(value, "ageTo");
          if (value) {
            ageFrom.setValidators(Validators.required);
          } else {
            ageFrom.setValidators(Validators.nullValidator);
          }
          ageFrom.updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false });
        });
      }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-upadtevalueandvalidity)